# using Renderer2 to get `selector` from within an Angular2 component

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-components

I am currently getting the 'selector' name like this and it works:-

```
constructor(public elem: ElementRef
{
    alert(this.elem.nativeElement.tagName.toLowerCase());
}
```

Tried to use Renderer2 but can't find any method which will allow me to get the tagName as above.
Don't want to use "NativeElement" directly - any suggestions

Thanks
Maiur

Comment: Renderer2 doesn't have any API that would allow you to do that. It seems that native API is your only option

Comment: There is no other way? Tried using ViewContainerRef but to no avail

Comment: not any I know of, `viewContainerRef` won't help, it's for different purposes, read [Exploring Angular DOM manipulation techniques using ViewContainerRef](https://blog.angularindepth.com/exploring-angular-dom-abstractions-80b3ebcfc02)